# how to change the system attribute scope from store to website

Tags: magento-1.8, store-view, scope

I am using magento 1.8.
**Note:**  I am using Advanced Permission to restrict user to a one store.

I am developing multistore appication where I need to set product **visibility = catalog, search** for all the store.

Means no need to select visibility in individual store scope.
How can I set the product visibility scope **global/website** from **store**

How can I change the scope from store to global/website level

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the attribute `visibility` from the backend in `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes` and set the scope to what ever you need.